# Why is the logic of init copied into another class function?

Tags: python

The snippet below is a simplified version of a long code in which the author has done something I don't quite understand.

```
from random import uniform

def outsider_function(input_class_object):
    input_class_object.suspicious_function()
    return input_class_object


class my_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = uniform(0,10)

    def suspicious_function(self):
        self.x = uniform(0,10)    

def run():
    input_class_object = my_class()
    my_class_object = outsider_function(input_class_object)

run()
```

In particular, the logic of the `__init__()` function of class `my_class` is copied into the member function `suspicious_function()`. Later, `suspicious_function()` is called in a non-member function `outsider_function()`. Is this logic duplication really the best way to achieve this? I mean, can't one simply call `__init__()` of `my_class` in `outsider_function()`?

Comment: In this case, both `__init__` and `suspicious_function` choose a random value for x.  I can imagine you might want to do that more than once over the lifetime of the class instance object, so yes, you would need some function other than `__init__` to do that.

Comment: `outsider_function` seems suspicious to me, why would it be needed? Is `input_class_object` the same object as `my_class_object`? `assert input_class_object is my_class_object`.

Comment: @wwii: No. `my_object_class` is not the same as `input_object_class`. What happens is that after `__init()__` creates a class object, that object will be consumed at some point, and (according to some conditions) `outsider_function()` is supposed to create another one for which `outsider_function()` invokes `suspicious_function()`.

Comment: The way you wrote your example, `assert input_class_object is my_class_object` does NOT throw an Exception. Those names point to the same object.

Comment: If you are woried about code duplication, `__init__` can be rewritten - `def __init__(self): self.suspicious_function()`.

Answer (score 2):

`__init__()` is a magic method, it is not supposed to be called by users.

I think it is better to call `suspicious_function()` inside `__init__()`.

```py
from random import uniform

def outsider_function(input_class_object):
    input_class_object.suspicious_function()
    return input_class_object


class my_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.suspicious_function()

    def suspicious_function(self):
        self.x = uniform(0,10)    

def run():
    input_class_object = my_class()
    my_class_object = outsider_function(input_class_object)

run()
```